# Adding AjaxControlToolkit stops postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a basic form with two textboxes and a drop-down value. The page works okay normally, but as soon as I add a reference to AjaxControlToolkit (which I'd like to use for the Calendar control), the PostBack stops working. The page is submitted, but eventually times out and never refreshes.
All I do to create this behaviour is add:
    `<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>`
after the Page directive, and then add:
     `<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="Server" />`
in the page body. I am NOT adding any reference to the Calendar (or any AJAX) controls at this stage.
Why won't the page refresh? Thanks.

Comment: I cannot replicate your error. Where did you get AjaxControlToolkit.dll? What version of Visual Studio and .Net Framework are you using?

Comment: I think the problem is actually an interaction with the Twitter Bootstrap framework...if I reduce the code to just the elements required it all works fine.

Comment: Okay, found the problem. I'm using a Master page. The ToolkitScriptManager has to be added immediately after the <form> tag, which was on the Master page. I had to add the assembly reference:
    `<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>`
on the Master page and the content page. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

Place the following tag inside `web.config` so that you do not have to include register tag in all pages.

```
<pages theme="Default">
  <controls>
    ....
    <add tagPrefix="asp" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" 
       namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    ....
  </controls>
</pages>
```